# How to include header image to a .ics file using php?

Tags: php, icalendar

I am trying to create a .ics file to send meeting request using php. Everything is well so far but now I must add an image to the invitation as a header for the body of the message.

How can I add a header image?
I tried to create a meeting using outlook, attach an image to it and then save as .ics file but I get a warning that the attached file may not be view able by all mail clients.

I tried ti add this code  but this did not work

Note I am trying to create the .ics file using php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is trying to add an image *in the event*. This is indeed not supported by standard iCalendar format.
But from what I understand you want to add an image in the *email* invitation that will go to each attendee. In that case, you simply replace the text/html bodypart in your invitation with a multipart/related containing a text/html bodypart and an image/xxx bodypart, and link the two with a content-id. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392

To get a concrete example, send an invitation from a Yahoo Calendar as they do send images along with invitation.

Here is the type of MIME structure that they send:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
   Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
      Content-Type: text/plain;
      Content-Type: multipart/related;
         Content-Type: text/html;
           ... your html version, which will include the image as <img src="cid:someuniqueid"/>
         Content-Type: image/gif;
         Content-ID: <someuniqueid>
           ... your image
      Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST
   Content-Type: application/ics; name="invite.ics"
```